# Error using Take to get the first 10 elements of a generic list

Tags: c#, list

I recently started learning C# and have to make a program that prints the first 10 members of the sequence `2, -3, 4, -5, 6, -7, ...`; but I get an error that I don't understand.

Here is my code:

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;


class PrintFirst10Elements
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        List<int> numberList = new List<int>() { 2, -3, 4, -5, 6, -7, 8, -9, 10, -11, };
        var firstFiveItems = List.Take(10); // error here on the call to Take
    }
}
```

The error message is:

> Using the generic type 'System.Collections.Generic.List' requires 1 type arguments.

What does "1 type arguments" mean? All elements are integers.

Comment: try `numberList.Take(10)`, the `Take` method is not a static method of the `List` class but a extension method

Comment: yeah that fixed it,but now I have other question.

    'Console.WriteLine(firstFiveItems);'

doesnt print numbers,but "System.Linq.Enumerable+<TakeIterator>d__3a`1[System.Int32]"

Comment: Technically, if the goal is really just to print the first 10 items in the sequence, there's no need for the Take() call at all--you initialize `numberList` with 10 items, so just use that.

Comment: `Console.WriteLine(String.Join(",",numberList.Take(10)));`

Comment: that because it will default use the `ToString` method which most time just prints the type, so you would probably have to loop over the list and write the items of `firstFiveItems` seperately; edit: or use @LB's solution which is also good

Comment: ty all for the quick help,you explained it simple enough so I can understand and the question can be marked as "Answered"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a couple things going on here:

1. As @Gunther34567 pointed out, you are trying to call the `Take` extension method as if it is a static method.  As a extension method, you need to call `Take` using an instance of `List<int>` rather than the class itself – so `numberList.Take(10)` rather than `List<int>.Take(10)`.
2. Even if `Take` was a static method, you would be trying to call it using an invalid class.  `List` is not a valid class: you would rather need `List<int>` as I showed above.  This is what the error message you saw was trying to explain – where `<int>` would be the required type argument.

Also, `firstFiveItems` is a pretty confusing name for a variable set by `Take(10)` (vs. `Take(5)`).

Answer (score 1):

Change `var firstFiveItems = List.Take(10);` to `var firstFiveItems = numberList.Take(10);` and it will work the way you want it.

As Gunther34567 already said, the [`Take` method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb503062(v=vs.110).aspx) is an extension method for the [`List` class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6sh2ey19%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).